# Creating a personal string vector class

Tags: c++

I am not allowed to make use of the vector class so I need to make my own. I made a int vector class and it works fine, but when trying to make it for strings it compiles but gives me an error because of the pointers. Any hint where I am making the mistake? All I did was change every int element for string, but aparently that does not work. Please help I am very confused.

```
    public:
        StringRow(){
            elements = new string;
            size = 0;
        }

        ~StringRow(){...} 

        void push_back(string value){...}

};
```

Comment: What is the error (the exact error message and at which line it occurs)? Also what do you see when debugging the code?

Comment: This does not compile, does it? Why not fix the compiler errors first? Post a [mcve] when it compiles.

Comment: First thing I notice: `elements = new string;` is *wrong* as you then later try to `delete[]` it as though it was an array. That's already *undefined behavior*

Comment: One error is that the class is `StringRow` but the constructor is still `IntRow`.

Comment: Please shown the code that works __and__ explain us what error message is displayed and when.

Comment: @MichaelWalz


The program does compile, but during execution there is some errors.
This is what I get after executing:

***Error in ./testProgram : free() invalid pointer: 0x0000009e192837128 **
======Backtrace: ======
/lib/x86_64 blablalbal
(repeating code)

=====Memory map: ========
9e2377b390--9e238905000 r-xp 000000000000 ca:5b00 115

(repeating code)

aborted (code dumped)

Comment: @nvoigt


The program does compile, but during execution there is some errors.
This is what I get after executing:

***Error in ./testProgram : free() invalid pointer: 0x0000009e192837128 **
======Backtrace: ======
/lib/x86_64 blablalbal
(repeating code)

=====Memory map: ========
9e2377b390--9e238905000 r-xp 000000000000 ca:5b00 115

(repeating code)

aborted (code dumped)

Comment: don't create a new String each time you push_back new element to vector. make an assumption on the size (guessing you are doing the same thing with integer too), reallocate only if initial size of the vector is not enough.

Comment: We are still waiting for a [mcve].

Comment: @Faulerhund please don't post clarifications in comments (they are unreadable), but [edit] your question instead. And post the [mcve]. You posted the class, but not how you use it.

Comment: you shouldn't ignore the warnings that are given to you by the compiler. Fix these first, then worry about why your program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You defined pointer to variable, not array of variables.

```
elements = new string;
```

Replace it with

```
elements = new string[size];
```

You can optimize algorithm with defining initial size. Create bigger array only if it's necessary.

Comment: You are right and thanks!!!!. I tried it, however I get a bad allocation exception. I don't really understand why is it doing this. Do you know??

This is the new error I get when running (it compiles ok)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what(): std::bad_alloc
aborted (core dumped)

Comment: This replacement will also invoke *undefined behavior* because `size` is not initialized at that point. `size = 0;` needs to be before this line

Comment: @UnholySheep I can't believe I missed it!!! Really I have been hours at this. Cheers!! thanks so much :)

Comment: This answer only addresses one problem.

Comment: is `new string[0]` allowed?

Comment: Why not? You allocate an 0 size array. You can't allocate negative size, but 0 is OK.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- in the constructor you don't need to allocate anything. You don't even need a constructor here, you can initialize the members directly as you declare them.
- if you allocate with `string* tmpElementsArray = new string[size + 1];` you need to deallocate with `delete [] tmpElementsArray`;

Corrected working version:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class StringRow {

private:
  string* elements = nullptr;
  int size = 0;

public:
//  constructor not needed
//    StringRow() {
//      elements = nullptr;
//     size = 0;
//    }

  ~StringRow() {
    delete []elements;
  }

  void push_back(string value) {

    string* tmpElementsArray = new string[size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
      tmpElementsArray[i] = elements[i];
    }

    delete [] elements;
    elements = tmpElementsArray;
    elements[size] = value;
    size++;
  }

  int length() {
    return size;
  }

  string at(int index) {
    if (index<size) {
      return elements[index];
    }
  }
};


int main()
{
  StringRow s;
  string str1 = "hello";
  string str2 = "hello2";
  s.push_back(str1);
  s.push_back(str2);

  cout << s.at(0) << endl ;
  cout << s.at(1) << endl;
}
```

Doing a `delete []elements` if `elements` is `nullptr` is OK.

NB: This is not the most efficient way.

Comment: most efficient way is to use std::vector :-)

Comment: @pm100 sure, but the OP is not supposed to use vector. It's an exercise.

Comment: I know that - hence the smiley

Comment: the `at` function is likely to crash if  `index >= size` because it is not returning a value even though its signature specifies it. In particular, if asked for optimizations the compiler will likely remove the `if (index < size)` check completely.